# Ionic2 emulate and run error

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.ionic.io/10-minutes-with-ionic-2-hello-world/) here in order to create a new and empty project. This works fine without any error.
However, afterwards I am executing the

```
ionic emulate android
```

command and I get the following errors:

```
Running 'emulate:before' gulp task before emulate  
[20:53:56] Starting 'clean'...  
[20:53:56] Finished 'clean' after 26 ms  
[20:53:56] Starting 'build'...  
[20:53:56] Starting 'sass'...  
[20:53:56] Starting 'html'...  
[20:53:56] Starting 'fonts'...  
[20:53:56] Starting 'scripts'...  
[20:53:56] Finished 'html' after 45 ms  
[20:53:56] Finished 'scripts' after 116 ms  
[20:53:56] Finished 'fonts' after 117 ms  
[20:53:57] Finished 'sass' after 961 ms  
[20:54:03] Finished 'build' after 7.61 s  
[20:54:03] Starting 'emulate:before'...  
[20:54:03] Finished 'emulate:before' after 2.77 μs  

• You're trying to build for androidbut don't have the platform installed yet.  
∆ Installing android for you.  
Installing cordova-plugin-device  
Installing cordova-plugin-console  
Installing cordova-plugin-whitelist  
Installing cordova-plugin-splashscreen  
Installing cordova-plugin-statusbar  
Installing ionic-plugin-keyboard  
Caught exception:  
 Error: Command failed: cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-splashscreen  
C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\configstore\index.js:69  
                                throw err;  
                                ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Myuser\.config\configstore\insight-cordova.json.1699442625' -> 'C:\Users\Myuser\.config\configstore\insight-cordova.json'
```

However, I am running this with Administrator privileges (Windows 10 pro) and I really don't know why I get this error.
If I execute the command

```
cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

manually, it works without any problems. But I do this with all commands that fail I end up in "unexcepted" errors without any concrete cause.

Right now I have no further idea how to fix this.

Comment: Seems like an issue with npm module cordova. Have you tried to remove it globally and reinstall it ? `npm remove -g cordova`  and `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: @e666 Yep I did this already...

Comment: Have you added android platform to your project.? In the error it shows that the android platform is not found.

Comment: @Aish123 yes I have - I always get this error. If I try to add the platform manually I get the "Error: Platform android already added." output...